# App cant find character device file when running inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash

im trying to start my serial port application inside a bash script. for some strange reason the application cannot fetch the /dev/ttyACM0 device file. if i type ls -la in /dev/ directly from a terminal the device file visible. When i try the same thing in a bash script every device file is visible except for the ttyACM0.

in terminal:

```
root@pc:~$ ls -la /dev/ttyAC*
crw-rw---T 1 root dialout 166, 0 Feb 18 17:25 /dev/ttyACM0
```

in script:

```
ls: cannot access /dev/ttyAC*: No such file or directory
```

All other device files are still visible.. Does someone have any idea how this is possible?

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# gpio defs
mcu_reset=49 #gpio2_17
mcu_erase=50 #gpio2_18

dir_export="/sys/class/gpio/export"
dir_reset="/sys/class/gpio/gpio$mcu_reset"
dir_erase="/sys/class/gpio/gpio$mcu_erase"

# Initialise Reset and erase gpio
if [ ! -d "$dir_reset" ]; then
  echo $mcu_reset > $dir_export
  echo out > "$dir_reset/direction"

  echo $mcu_erase > $dir_export
  echo out > "$dir_erase/direction"

  echo 0 > "$dir_erase/value"
  echo 1 > "$dir_reset/value"
  echo "* GPIO directories initialised!"
fi

# erase mcu flash
echo "* Erasing device..."
echo 1 > "$dir_erase/value"
sleep 0.5
echo 0 > "$dir_erase/value"
sleep 0.5

# reset device
echo "* Resetting device..."
echo 0 > "$dir_reset/value"
sleep 0.5
echo 1 > "$dir_reset/value"
sleep 0.5

# Flash device
#$(bossac -e -d -w -v -b argv[0])
ls -la /dev/ttyAC*

# reset device
echo "* Resetting device..."
echo 0 > "$dir_reset/value"
sleep 0.5
echo 1 > "$dir_reset/value"
sleep 0.5
```

Comment: Could you post the full script?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! When 'echo 1 > "$dir_reset/value" gets executed the mcu connected to linux resets. the sleep of 0.5 seconds was to short for the mcu to come up again.